# ElasticSearch delete all data

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have this code which select 100 records from Product table and then `DeleteManyAsync` (from NEST package) to remove all of them. How do I select all the data instead of need to hardcode the value 100?

```
 var documents = _elasticClient.Search<Product>(
                s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll())
                .Size(100)
            );

 var enumerable = documents.Hits.Select(h => h.Source);

 await _elasticClient.DeleteManyAsync<Product>(enumerable);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to delete all data from index, you don't need to query it first and transfer to the client. Simply use [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html):

```
await _elasticClient.DeleteByQueryAsync<Product>(
    s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll())
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the records from the index, then why not just delete the index and creates a new one, this way it would be much faster and cheaper to do.

Please refer [delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) for more info.